'#1^n' appearing at the solution of Eigenvalues
I have been trying to get the eigenvalue of a known Hamiltonian which is given by 
By manual calculation I know that at least one of the eigenvalues is e_s but when I try to use the eigenvalue function of mathematica it gives the form
I don't understand what is #1 here and how is it giving the eigenvalue as e_s?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! There are several problems here. (1) Please don't use screenshots when posting a question. Instead, copy and paste your Mathematica code directly. (2) You shouldn't use underscores (_) in variable names, because they have a special meaning. (3) For imaginary unit, you should use uppercase I instead of lowercase i. (4) How do I work with Root objects?.

Please edit your question according to Domen's comment. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

Too long for comment
You should not use e_s as variable name. the _ is special in Mathematica. Also watch out for your Kx, need space. I assume this is meant to be k*x. And also fixed your complex i.
I always use explicit * for multiplication to avoid this problem of using space to mean multiplication. I am old fashioned.
To remove those funny 1# things, use ToRadicals, like this
H2 = {{es, W + Exp[-2*a (I*k*x)], 0}, 
      {W + Exp[2*a*I*k*x]*W, es, 2*W}, 
      {0, 2*W, es}};

MatrixForm[H2]


Eigenvalues[H2] // ToRadicals



You have a typo in the first entry. Should be es, then you get a short result for the three eigenvalues and one of the eigenvalues is es indeed

@MichaelWeyrauch yes, fixed typo. Now it is much shorter.

And you do not need //ToRadicals.

yes, after the typo fix, ToRadicals is not needed. But I kept there to answer you original question of how to get rid of the Roots objects just in case you end up changing the input again and these come back. Feel free to remove it in your code.
